# Determining the units in large rings from units in smaller ones

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In my abstract algebra class we recently discussed the quadratic integer rings $\mathcal{O}$ (as in Dummit and Foote, section 7.1). For $D$ a squarefree integer, it was shown that there is a *field norm* $N:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D)\to\mathbb{Q}$, $N(a+b\sqrt D)=a^2-Db^2$, which is multiplicative and satisfies $N(\mathcal{O})\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$, such that an element $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}$ is a unit if and only if $N(\alpha)=\pm1$ - the units in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Another example of a ring with such a norm is the ring $M_n(R)$ of $n\times n$ matrices over the commutative unital ring $R$. The norm in this case is the determinant map - a matrix $A\in M_n(R)$ is a unit if and only if $\det A$ is a unit in $R$. Note that the determinant map is also multiplicative.

How much does this generalize? For these two examples we have a multiplicative map to a ring which is smaller than the original one (at least, in the sense that the codomain can be embedded into the domain), from which we deduce information about the units of the original ring via units in the new one. Do all commutative unital rings admit a similar map?

Sorry for the vague question. I'm an analyst but trying to learn more algebra, so I don't have the language yet to phrase this more precisely.

Comment: Indeed, the question is a bit vague. The first example of course generalizes to general number fields and their integer rings or orders, but I don't know how to answer your main question which is "**how much** does this generalize". It would be more answerable if you have some specific examples or applications.

Comment: If by "smaller than the original one" you mean *strictly* smaller, then I think we run into an issue with the integers. There is only one ring map (taking $1$ to $1$) out of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Both examples you cite are actually determinants, in some sense. Indeed, your first norm map can be defined for any finite extension of fields $K/F$. Set $n = [K:F]$, and let $l_{x} \colon K \to K$ be the $F$-linear map given by sending $y \in K$ to $xy$. The association $K \to \mathrm{End}_{F}(K)$ sending $x$ to $l_{x}$ is multiplicative, and the norm map $N_{K/F} \colon K \to F$ sends $x \to \det(l_{x})$. (I don't know whether the norm characterizes units in general, however - that part may be specific to quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. I'd have to think about it.)